# Adding a layout in a listitem

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

i Have custom listview  like this

[image]

I have to add an another list view below Account-1 which shows rest of the accounts as shown

[image]

How can i put another Listview inside a listview only for the first item of the outer list.

Please help.

Comment: Why you wanna only use one ListView? Because of the Drawer (it looks like it)?This is a nightmare.. Have different Views for this which would be much more dynamic.

Comment: Go To menu belong to custom list view or is another view ?